# Why is this ZipArchive oracle off by 5-10 bytes?

Tags: c#, .net, zip

I'm using [ZipArchive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive(v=vs.110).aspx) and I'm writing an oracle that determines the size of a zip file based on the [zip specification](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT). For simplicity, no compression is being used.

```
private long ZipSizeOracle(int numOfFiles, int totalLengthOfFilenames, int totalSizeOfFiles)
{
    return
        numOfFiles * (
        30 //Local file header
        +
        12 //Data descriptor
        + 
        46 //Central directory file header
        ) 
        + 
        2 * totalLengthOfFilenames //Local file header name + Central directory file header name
        + 
        totalSizeOfFiles //Data size
        + 22 //End of central directory record (EOCD)
        ;
    }
```

Currently I have 4 tests, `ZeroFiles` outputs 22 bytes correctly and is the appropriate size for an empty zip.

```
[TestMethod]
public void ZeroFiles()
{
    using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var archive = new ZipArchive(memStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true)) { }

        Assert.AreEqual(ZipSizeOracle(0, 0, 0), memStream.Length);
    }
}
```

`One4ByteFile` expects 130 bytes but the actual was 125 bytes

```
[TestMethod]
public void One4ByteFile()
{
    using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var archive = new ZipArchive(memStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true)) 
        {
            var entry1 = archive.CreateEntry("test.txt", CompressionLevel.NoCompression);
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(entry1.Open()))
                writer.WriteLine("test");
        }

        Assert.AreEqual(ZipSizeOracle(1, 8, 4), memStream.Length);
    }
}
```

`Two4ByteFiles` expects 241 bytes but the actual was 231 bytes

```
[TestMethod]
public void Two4ByteFiles()
{
    using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var archive = new ZipArchive(memStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
        {
            var entry1 = archive.CreateEntry("test.txt", CompressionLevel.NoCompression);
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(entry1.Open()))
                writer.WriteLine("test");

            var entry2 = archive.CreateEntry("test2.txt", CompressionLevel.NoCompression);
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(entry2.Open()))
                writer.WriteLine("test2");
        }

        Assert.AreEqual(ZipSizeOracle(2, 17, 9), memStream.Length);
    }
}
```

`OneFolder` expects 118 bytes but the actual was 108 bytes

```
[TestMethod]
public void OneFolder()
{
    using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var archive = new ZipArchive(memStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
            archive.CreateEntry(@"test\", CompressionLevel.NoCompression);

        Assert.AreEqual(ZipSizeOracle(1, 4, 0), memStream.Length);
    }
}
```

What am I missing from the specification in order for the oracle to give me the correct file size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the following:

1. Data descriptor block is optional and is included only if zip file is written in "streamed" manner (that is - you don't know size of file beforehand and write "on the fly"). When you are streaming - size of compressed and uncompressed data, as well as CRC, are not available when file header is written (because file header goes before data), so all those bytes in file header are set to 0 and data descriptor block is included *after* compressed data, when this information is available. In case of examples you provided - data descriptor is not included.
2. Level `NoCompression` in `CreateEntry` does not mean data is included literally. Instead, data is processed with deflate algorithm (compression method 8 in specification you linked) without actual compression. This deflate algorithm adds its own overhead, even in "no compression mode":

   - 1 byte defines if this is a last block or not and compression level.
   - 2 bytes define block size
   - 2 bytes define two-complement of block size (for integrity)
   - then goes the data with size defined above

So for each block of data in input (block is 2^16 bytes) - 5 bytes of overhead are added. In your examples all files are less than 2^16 in size, so just 5 bytes are added for them.

3. You use `writer.WriteLine`, so size of data you write is not 4 bytes in first example, but 6, because `\r\n` (newline characters) are added (and in second example that is 13).

If you take all this into account (remove 12 data descriptor size, add 5 size of deflate overhead for your small files, pass correct `totalSizeOfFiles`) - your examples will produce expected output.

Update about data descriptor record. Specification says:

> This descriptor SHOULD be used only when it was not possible to
>         seek in the output .ZIP file, e.g., when the output .ZIP file
>         was standard output or a non-seekable device

And `ZipArchive` class follows this. If you pass unseekable stream in constructor - it will emit data descriptor records. For example:

```
public class UnseekableStream : MemoryStream {
    public override bool CanSeek => false;
}

using (var memStream = new UnseekableStream()) {
    using (var archive = new ZipArchive(memStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true)) { 
   }
 }
```

Such unseekable streams often happen in practice, http response stream is one example. But note that 12 bytes is not the only allowed size for data descriptor record:

> ```
>   4.3.9.3 Although not originally assigned a signature, the value 
>   0x08074b50 has commonly been adopted as a signature value 
>   for the data descriptor record.  Implementers should be 
>   aware that ZIP files may be encountered with or without this 
>   signature marking data descriptors and SHOULD account for
>   either case when reading ZIP files to ensure compatibility.
>
>   4.3.9.4 When writing ZIP files, implementors SHOULD include the
>   signature value marking the data descriptor record.  When
>   the signature is used, the fields currently defined for
>   the data descriptor record will immediately follow the
>   signature.
> ```

So, data descriptor may optionally start with 4 bytes signature, and it is recommended for implementors to include that signature when writing, and `ZipArchive` follows this recommendation, so size of data descriptor record it emits is 16 bytes (12 + 4 of signature), not 12.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Those corrections work perfectly. One followup question if possible. If I am writing a zipfile to a stream in a "streamed" manner do I just need the 12 bytes for the data descriptor or is there another piece I am missing for my oracle to support that?

Comment: @Shoe I've updated my answer with more information about data desrciptor record.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much. I ran some tests with an unseekable stream and got the correct outputs.